# Regarding Generalized Solutions to Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

There are certain functions that can be non-differntiable but are still solution to a "differential equations".

This is fine, as a non-differentiable function can still have an integral.

The main question is the following:

**What does it mean by taking the Laplace transform of Non-differntiable functions.?**

**Isnt it a violation of some rules here and there?**

Comment: I don't think differentiability is required.

Comment: Could you please elaborate or make the argument more Concrete.

Comment: Sure!

Differentiating a non-differentiable function.

Comment: I see!  Although, what is the significance of a non-differentiable solution to a differential equation.

Comment: As in, say a function y is not differentiable.

Comment: Then. What does it mean by taking the Laplace transform of y' or y"

Comment: 1st eg: Laplace transforms of Heaviside Step Function and Dirac delta.

Comment: 2nd Eg: 2y" +y' + 2y=u_5(t) -u_20(t)

Comment: Here u_5(t) refers to Heaviside step function "jumped" at 5. Similarly  u_10(t)

Comment: 3rd e.g. 2y"+y'+2y=delta(at 5) I.e. impulse at x=5

Comment: The final solution we get is non-differentiable. So y' or y" shouldn't even exist in the 1st place

Comment: Although... I could "cheat" My way, I ignore the 'singularity" point, and differentiate everywhere else

Answer (score -1):

Laplace transform is an integral and works for any integrable function does not matter if its differentiable or not with a certain Region of Convergence region. Your question to be put precise i think is what happens when you do, $L^{-1} (s \times L(f(x)))$ where $f(x)$ is non-differentiable. The thing is laplace transform being an integral based transform allows impulses $\delta(x)$ as functions which will allow differentiation of a lot more functions. For the functions like $|x|$ where the derivative just does not converge, Laplace transform also does not give proper results at those points.

So $L^{-1} (s \times L(f(x)))$ will differentiate $f(x)$ properly but only except for the points of $x$ where left derivative and right derivative does not converge. It will put values at these non-differentiable points to make sure that transform and inverse transform is consistent i.e., the integral equation of transform works.

Further since measure of these discrete set of points is $0$. So when you use Laplace transform, the solution is unique only upto a countably many points of $x$. So we impose continuity constraint on the solution and make it unique.